# how to call a primary key from a table to another one in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, database

I have this code where I specify the userid, what I want please (as I have a table in my database called tbl_registration and it has a user_id) as you can see in my code i specified the $userid= 3, I want that to be depends on the id that the register user has please. it is a rating function and if you have a way to that,this will make only registered user to rate any movie at most once for each movie. I will be happy if you can help me with this, thanks

rating.php

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$userid = 3;
$movieId = $_POST['movie_id'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];

// Check entry within table
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntpost FROM post_rating WHERE movie_id=".$movieId." and userid=".$userid;

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$fetchdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count = $fetchdata['cntpost'];

if($count == 0){
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO post_rating(userid,movie_id,rating) values(".$userid.",".$movieId.",".$rating.")";
    mysqli_query($con,$insertquery);
}else {
  $insertquery = "INSERT INTO post_rating(user_d,movie_id,rating) values(".$userid.",".$movieId.",".$rating.")";
  mysqli_query($con,$insertquery);
}


// get average
$query = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as averageRating FROM post_rating WHERE movie_id=".$movieId;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
$fetchAverage = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$averageRating = $fetchAverage['averageRating'];

$return_arr = array("averageRating"=>$averageRating);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

movies.php

```
<?php include('header.php');?>
<br/>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='jquery-bar-rating-master/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Script -->
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-bar-rating-master/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $('.rating').barrating({
                theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
                onSelect: function(value, text, event) {

                        // Get element id by data-id attribute
                        var el = this;
                        var el_id = el.$elem.data('id');

                        // rating was selected by a user
                        if (typeof(event) !== 'undefined') {

                                var split_id = el_id.split("_");

                                var movie_id = split_id[1];  // postid

                                // AJAX Request
                                $.ajax({
                                        url: 'rating_ajax.php',
                                        type: 'post',
                                        data: {movie_id:movie_id,rating:value},
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function(data){
                                                // Update average
                                                var average = data['averageRating'];
                                                $('#avgrating_'+movie_id).text(average);
                                        }
                                });
                        }
                }
        });
});

</script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1 class="style-text text-center"><strong>All Movies</strong></h1><br/ ><br>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="content-top">

            <?php
                        $userid=3;
             $qry2= "select * from  tbl_movie order by rand()";
                         $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry2);
              while($m=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                   {
                                         $movieId = $m['movie_id'];
                                         $image = $m['image'];
                                         $movieName = $m['movie_name'];
                                         $type = $m['type'];
                                         // User rating
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM post_rating WHERE movie_id=".$movieId." and userid=".$userid;
                    $userresult = mysqli_query($con,$qry2) or die(mysqli_error());
                    $fetchRating = mysqli_fetch_array($userresult);
               //   $rating = $fetchRating['rating'];
                                        $rating = isset($_GET['rating']) ? $_GET['rating'] : '';
                    // get average
                    $qry2 = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as averageRating FROM post_rating WHERE movie_id=".$movieId;
                    $avgresult = mysqli_query($con,$qry2) or die(mysqli_error());
                    $fetchAverage = mysqli_fetch_array($avgresult);
                    $averageRating = $fetchAverage['averageRating'];

                    if($averageRating <= 0){
                        $averageRating = "No rating yet.";
                    }
            ?>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                        <div class="imageRow">
                        <div class="single">
                        <a href="about.php?id=<?php echo $movieId;?>"><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="" width=180 height=280/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div clsss='post'>
                        <!-- Rating -->
                        <select class='rating <?php echo $movieId; ?>' data-id='rating_<?php echo $movieId; ?>'>
                                <option value="1" >1</option>
                                <option value="2" >2</option>
                                <option value="3" >3</option>
                                <option value="4" >4</option>
                                <option value="5" >5</option>
                        </select>

                        Average Rating : <span id='avgrating_<?php echo $movieId; ?>'><?php echo $averageRating; ?></span>
                        <div class="movie-text">
                        <h4 class="h-text"><a href="about.php?id=<?php echo $movieId;?>"><?php echo $movieName;?></a></h4>
                        Type: <Span class="color2"><?php echo $type;?></span><br/></br/>

                            <!-- Set rating -->
                            <script type='text/javascript'>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('<?php echo $movieId; ?>').barrating('set',<?php echo $rating; ?>);
                            });

                            </script>


                                                    </div>  </div>  </div>

</div>

        <?php
            }
            ?>
            </div></div></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

            <?php include('footer.php');?>
```

Comment: Welcome this is your first question. May I suggest you start with an explanation of your problem, followed by details of everything you have already done to try and resolve it and conclude with your expectation. Focus each question on only one problem and keep in mind no one else knows about the application that you are building but we do know a lot about the language, frameworks, APIs, etc which you are working with. The more information you give about that the easier it will be to attract a knowledgeable user who has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: When the user logs in, put their userid in a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because there is a **serious security flaw** in your code and performance issues!

First, you have what we call "SQL Injection" :

```php
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntpost FROM post_rating WHERE movie_id=".$movieId." and userid=".$userid;
$query="SELECT * FROM post_rating WHERE movie_id=".$movieId." and userid=".$userid;
```

This should use prepared statement as described in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).
Details on SQL Injection can be found in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Second is the infamous "order by rand()". Don't do that! It is very slow as the DB has to scan the full table AND "rand()" is unstable. That means the shuffling will be SLOW and biased. You may be better of taking few random rows from client side. Also, put a limit: today 10 rows, in a week 100 etc.

Avoid the "*" in selects. You will be retrieving columns you do not need!

For the main question, you want your user to connect to your system using an authentication system like a couple username/password.

Then you want to start a ([server side session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)).

From there, you will be able to store and retrieve any information you need, including userID.

It's also a good thing to check how [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) work.

Personal advice: read the manual entries in [language reference](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php)